# Oracle JDBC PoolDataSource not releasing DB cursors?

Tags: java, oracle

I am executing queries using a `Connection` obtained from `oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource`. It seems that the DB cursors these queries open are not closed when I close the DB resources, only when the Pool reuses the connection, or when the JVM exits.

I am checking for open cursors by running the below query.

```
select SQL_TEXT, v$open_cursor .* from v$open_cursor 
where 
user_name = 'ME'
AND 
CURSOR_TYPE = 'OPEN'
```

When the code reaches the first sleep, the query returns `select 1 from dual a`, `select 1 from dual b` at the second seleep, etc... Once the JVM exits my query returns no results.

So, it seems the cursors are remaining open until another query is executed or the JVM exits. Any suggestions how I can ensure the cursors are reliably closed when I close the `statement`/`connection`/`resultSet`?

```
    pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    pooledDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ":1521/" + service);
    pooledDataSource.setUser(user);
    pooledDataSource.setPassword(pw);
    pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1);
    pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
    pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    pooledDataSource.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(60);
    pooledDataSource.setConnectionWaitTimeout(60);
    pooledDataSource.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(60);


    try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual a");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("opened a");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual b");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("opened b");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual c");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("opened c");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: @Alex Poole this statement: `try( Closeable ..... ){..... }` is so called [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), all opened resources including statements are automatically closed.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.orafaq.com/node/758), in short `v$open_cursor` shows cached cursors, not currently open cursors.

Comment: @krokodilko I get the same results if I use this query from the article you linked.... during each `sleep`, the query shows the same SIDs as the query in my post: `select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid
and b.name = 'opened cursors current'`

Comment: Well, you are using pooled datasource. Oracle creates a pool of connections and keeps them opened in the pool. Your code is borrowing the connection from the pool, and calling `close` on the connection does not close physicall connection, but only returns it to the pool, the connection is still opened.